# ThingsBoard Inactivity Events Not creating alarms

Tags: thingsboard

I am working with the following [guide:](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/create-inactivity-alarm/). I am not able to get any alarms created.
According to the guide, I must create an inactivityTimeout, in the guide it sets it to 60000, I have set it to 10000.

[image: Server Attribute - inactivityTimout = 1000]

I then edited the root rule chain:
[image: Edited Root Rule Chain]

Here is the function details in the Create Inactivity Alarm:

```
if (metadata.prevAlarmDetails) {
    details = JSON.parse(metadata.prevAlarmDetails);
}


return details;
```

Here is a screenshot of the Create Inactivity Alarm node:
[image: Create Inactivity Alarm Node]

Below is the function for the Clear Inactivity Alarm Node:

```
if (metadata.prevAlarmDetails) {
    details = JSON.parse(metadata.prevAlarmDetails);
}
return details;
```

And here is the screenshot for the Clear Inactivity Alarm Node:
[image: Clear Inactivity Alarm Node]

When I post using Postman:
[image: postman screenshot]

I get the value in the latest telemetry:
[image: IRMS out Value]

But nothing in the alarms section of the specific device:
[image: No Alarms Found]

I have also tried to set alarms in device profile for activity and for the IRMS value and when the conditions are met, there are still no alarms being set.

I have double checked as I notice that the guide i followed was for the thingsboard.io
So i followed this guide as well:
[Guide for thinsboard.cloud](https://thingsboard.io/docs/paas/getting-started-guides/helloworld/#step-4-configure-alarm-rules)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I have also noticed that when i set a low threshold, say 10 and then try to post a numeric value lower than that, the telemetry does not reflect. When i post a numeric value higher than the the low threshold point, the value immediately appears in the telemetry. 
Similarly when I turn on my device and transmit data and purposely bring the sensor data below the low point threshold, the telemetry feed for that specific data point freezes.

Comment: Did you change the default rule chain for the device profile? so that the Root Rule Chain isn't triggered at all?